# Ubuntu - Kannel Stopped Receiving Messages After 6 Hours

Tags: ubuntu, kannel

If you check the terminal, there is no error printed. I need to restart the kannel. The alive state of the modem is down. The sim card is stuck. There must a way to restart the kannel automatically.

Please help. Thanks in advance!